# webBrowser_DocumentCompleted called 4 times for no reason (that I can find)

Tags: c#, html, forum

**I'm out of ideas...**

Hi guys, I got little to no knowledge in C# and Html Documents/Elements and something weird happens while using DocumentCompleted. Here's the DocumentCompleted code and the PostGame() code :

```
    private void WB_CHL_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Date != "")
            PostGame();
        else
            this.Close();
    }

    private void PostGame()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = null;
        doc = WB_CHL.Document;

        HtmlElementCollection inputelems = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        inputelems.GetElementsByName("subject")[0].SetAttribute("value", Date);

        doc.GetElementById("text_editor_textarea").SetAttribute("value", Games);

        HtmlElementCollection inputbutton = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        inputbutton.GetElementsByName("post")[0].Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
```

And here's the HTML source code :

```
    </head><body background="https://i39.servimg.com/u/f39/17/72/44/45/backgr10.jpg" bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000"><a name="top"></a><table class="bodylinewidth" width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" align="center"><tr><td class="bodyline"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center" width="100%" valign="middle"><a href="/"><img src="https://i58.servimg.com/u/f58/17/72/44/45/ovechk14.jpg" id="i_logo" border="0" alt="Crazy Hockey League" vspace="1" /></a><br /><div class="maintitle">Crazy Hockey League</div><br /><span class="gen">CHL Franchise™.<br />&nbsp; </span></td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center"><tr><td align="center"><a class="mainmenu" href="/"><img id="i_icon_mini_index" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/home15.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Accueil" title="Accueil" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/calendar"><img id="i_icon_mini_calendar" src="https://illiweb.com/fa/empty.gif" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Calendrier" title="Calendrier" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/faq"><img id="i_icon_mini_faq" src="https://illiweb.com/fa/empty.gif" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="FAQ" title="FAQ" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/memberlist"><img id="i_icon_mini_members" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/membre12.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Membres" title="Membres" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/groups"><img id="i_icon_mini_groups" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/groupe11.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Groupes" title="Groupes" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/profile?mode=editprofile"><img id="i_icon_mini_profile" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/profil11.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Profil" title="Profil" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/privmsg?folder=inbox" rel="nofollow"><img id="i_icon_mini_message" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/mp11.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Messagerie" title="Messagerie" /></a><a class="mainmenu" href="/login?logout=1&amp;tid=0162d102f01a1c63d64d8d517645b5ae&amp;key=7a24f2" rel="nofollow" id="logout" ><img id="i_icon_mini_logout" src="https://i38.servimg.com/u/f38/17/18/20/77/off11.png" border="0"  hspace="0" alt="Déconnexion [ Ogie ]" title="Déconnexion [ Ogie ]" /></a></td></tr></table><div style="clear: both;"></div><div id="page-body"><div id="emptyidcc" class="no-left"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="three-col"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="0"><div id="emptyidleft"></div></td><td valign="top" width="100%"><div class='n99fdc1'><script src="https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-0339214227387817");    GS_googleEnableAllServices();//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    GA_googleAddAttr("Ad_type", "text");    GA_googleAddAttr("User_type", "Regular_user");GA_googleAddAttr("Page_type", "Other_page");GA_googleAddAttr("Site_type", "Premium");GA_googleAddAttr("Gender", "Male");GA_googleAddAttr("AgeRange", "18-24");//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    google_ad_slot="1505882794";    google_ad_channel="2442858061+9170118551+4515235772+8811049474+2562183790+8771478709+2207379944+8003782320";    google_ad_type="text";    google_color_border="ffffff";    google_color_link="000000";    google_color_bg="ffffff";    google_color_text="000000";    google_color_url="ffffff";    google_ui_features="rc:6";    google_font="Arial";    google_font_size="Small";    google_alternate_ad_url="https://www.adstune.com/personal_ads/?bg_color=ffffff&amp;body_link=000000&amp;text_color=000000&amp;url_color=000000&amp;dateid=749406&amp;lang=fr&amp;cat=369&amp;force=1&amp;flang=fr";    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_ad_slot", google_ad_slot);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_ad_channel", google_ad_channel);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_ad_type", "text");    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_color_border", google_color_border);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_color_link", google_color_link);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_color_bg", google_color_bg);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_color_text", google_color_text);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_color_url", google_color_url);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_ui_features", google_ui_features);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_font", google_font);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_font_size", google_font_size);    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("728x90-top", "google_alternate_ad_url", google_alternate_ad_url);//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    GA_googleUseIframeRendering();//]]>
</script><script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
GA_googleFillSlotWithSize("ca-pub-0339214227387817", "728x90-top", 728, 90);//]]>
</script><br class="clear" /></div><div style="clear:both;"></div><style type="text/css">html body .n99fdc1,html body .n99fdc1 iframe,html body iframe[name="google_ads_frame"],html body .n99fdc1 iframe[name="google_ads_frame"],html body #wrap #page-body div.n99fdc1,html body #page-body .n99fdc1,html body div.n99fdc1{display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;float:none!important;left:inherit!important;top:inherit!important;right:inherit!important;bottom:inherit!important;margin:0 auto!important;filter:alpha(opacity=100)!important;-moz-opacity:1!important;-khtml-opacity:1!important;opacity:1!important;z-index:9999!important;text-align:center!important}html body .n99fdc1,html body .n99fdc1 iframe[name="google_ads_frame"]{width:728px!important;height:90px!important;min-height:90px!important}html body .n99fdc1 iframe{border:0px!important}html body iframe[name="google_ads_frame"]{width:100%!important;height:inherit!important;min-height:inherit!important}</style><div style="height:3px"></div><script src="https://illiweb.com/rsc/16/frm/extendedview.js" type="text/javascript"></script><form action="/post" method="post" name="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr><td><span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="/">Crazy Hockey League</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;::&nbsp;<h1><a href="/c7-chl-simulation" class="nav"><span>CHL | Simulation</span></a></h1>&nbsp;::&nbsp;<h1><a href="/f29-resultats" class="nav"><span>Résultats</span></a></h1></span></td></tr></table><table class="forumline" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"><tr><th height="28" class="thHead" colspan="2" valign="bottom"><strong>Poster un nouveau sujet</strong></th></tr><tr><td class="row1" width="22%"><span class="gen"><b>Titre du sujet</b></span></td><td class="row2" width="78%"><span class="gen"><input class="post" style="width:450px" type="text" name="subject" value="" size="45" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" title="La longueur du titre de ce sujet doit être comprise entre 1 et 255 caractères" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" /><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
input = document.getElementsByName('subject');//]]></script><select name="topic_color" onchange="input[0].style.color = topic_color.value" style="margin-left:10px"><option value="#660000" style="color:#660000;" >Rouge foncé</option><option value="#FF0000" style="color:#FF0000;" >Rouge</option><option value="#FF9933" style="color:#FF9933;" >Orange</option><option value="#663300" style="color:#663300;" >Marron</option><option value="#FFFF00" style="color:#FFFF00;" >Jaune</option><option value="#006600" style="color:#006600;" >Vert</option><option value="#666633" style="color:#666633;" >Olive</option><option value="#00FFFF" style="color:#00FFFF;" >Cyan</option><option value="#0000FF" style="color:#0000FF;" >Bleu</option><option value="#000099" style="color:#000099;" >Bleu foncé</option><option value="#6600FF" style="color:#6600FF;" >Indigo</option><option value="#999999" style="color:#999999;" >Gris</option><option value="#FFFFFF" style="color:#CCCCCC;" >Blanc</option><option value="#000000" style="color:#000000;" >Noir</option><option value="" style="color:;" selected="selected">Aucune</option></select><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
input[0].style.color = '';//]]></script></span></td></tr><tr><td class="row1" width="22%"><span class="gen"><b>Description</b></span></td><td class="row2" width="78%"><span class="gen"><input class="post" style="width:450px" type="text" name="description" value="" maxlength="255" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" /></span></td></tr><tr id="parent_editor_simple" ><td class="row1" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><tr><td><span class="gen" style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Corps du message</b></span></td></tr><tr><td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr align="center"><td class="gensmall" colspan=""><div id="smileyContainer"><script type="text/javascript">function addSmileyPane() { $("#smileyContainer").html('<iframe name="smilies" src="/smilies.forum?mode=smilies_frame&amp;t=1509143808" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" height="350" width="220" class="row1"></iframe>'); }</script></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td class="row2" valign="top"><span class="genmed"></span><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td valign="top"><textarea id="text_editor_textarea" class="post" name="message" tabindex="3" wrap="virtual"></textarea>&nbsp;</td><td id="smileyContainer" valign="top"><script type="text/javascript">function addSmileyPane() { $("#smileyContainer").html('<iframe name="smilies" src="/smilies.forum?mode=smilies_frame&amp;t=1509143808" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" height="350" width="220" class="row1"></iframe>'); }</script></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table class="forumline" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="catBottom" colspan="2" align="center" height="28"><input type="hidden" name="lt" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="auth[]" value="c1900dead7de9ece4c5a991c880e82f0" /><input type="hidden" name="auth[]" value="1233e4038430dbd924cc1448d5f042f3" /><input type="hidden" name="mode" value="newtopic" /><input type="hidden" name="f" value="29" /><input class="liteoption" type="submit" name="preview" value="Prévisualiser" tabindex="5" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="mainoption" type="submit" name="post" value="Envoyer" tabindex="6" accesskey="s" /></td></tr></table><br /><br />
```

So the problem is that the DocumentCompleted/PostGame() function have to be called 4 times before performing the post.

1st turn : When it meets this line, it throws an exception

```
    inputelems.GetElementsByName("subject")[0].SetAttribute("value", Date);

    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value of '0' is not valid for 
    'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
    Parameter name: index
```

2nd turn : Same thing as 1st turn happens

3rd turn : Goes through all the PostGame() function, but doesn't post on the forum. (This part of code doesn't seem to toggle well)

```
    HtmlElementCollection inputbutton = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    inputbutton.GetElementsByName("post")[0].Focus();
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

4th turn : Goes through all the PostGame() function and posts on the forum properly.

**I'm all new to this... I've tried to Debug and find the issue(s) for over 3 hours and couldn't find it/them... Please help me !!!**

**Thanks guys !**

Comment: Like I said, I'm relatively new to this, so what do you mean by sample inputs ? As for the expected ouput, my goal to achieve is to do an automatic game poster for a simulated hockey forum. There's a simulator program which exports results as simple text, I read this page, parse the informations I want (split games by day of play). The program I'm making have two dialogs. First one asks at what date do you want the program to start posting games and the second one is the web browser that posts the info automatically.

Comment: I posted the source code that way so you can see, else you would have to make an account and get accepted as a General Manager on the forum to access the post function.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your full HTML, but I can tell that it contains some `iframe`s. The `DocumentCompleted` is invoked when - surprise - the document has finished loading.

But if you have multiple `iframe`s in the HTML, then you have multiple documents.

So it will be invoked multiple times when each `iframe` finished loading the document it's pointing to.

You can check the `Url` property of the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` parameter in the event handler to see which document loaded. If you only want to handle the main page load, you should be able to do it with:

```
private void OnWebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;

    if (e.Url == webBrowser.Url)
    {
        // main page loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can't post the full HTML code because of the character restrictions, but I will try what you suggest ! Thanks !

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix my original problem. I still get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException :/ You need to insert this function inside DocumentCompleted right ? And I would put what I had in DocumentCompleted originally in the if statement ?

Comment: if you get the exception that means the main document is not ready. you need to skip the events from iframes.